# Is this naive division-by-subtraction complexity O(n) or O(2^n)?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
def subtraction_div(dividend: int, divisor: int) -> int:
    if (dividend < 0 and divisor > 0) or (dividend > 0 and divisor < 0):
        sign = -1
    else:
        sign = 1
    dividend = abs(dividend)
    divisor = abs(divisor)
    quotient = 0
    while dividend - divisor > 0:
        quotient += 1
        dividend -= divisor
    if sign < 0:
        quotient = - quotient
    return quotient
```

I think the time complexity is O(N) while my CS degree friend lists some hard-to-understand formula to me and telling me it's O(2^N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is the number of bits needed to represent the argument, not the largest possible magnitude (which we can call `N`). `N` grows exponentially in `n`, not linearly, and the number of subtractions depends on `N`. (Ergo, the number of subtractions is exponential in the input size, QED.)

Intuitively, `subtraction_div(100, 5)` makes 10 times more subtractions than `subtraction_div(10, 5)`, even though the input size is only 1 digit larger. (The number of bits in the binary representation is roughly a constant factor of 3 greater than the number of digits, so we basically ignore the difference between bits and digits when talking about time complexity here.)

---

You can trivially *make* the algorithm O(n) by saying that the arguments are provided as base-1 bits strings, so that the bit size and the magnitude are identical, but time complexity is only useful if you restrict yourself to *efficient* encodings. Any (positive integer) base other than 1 is equivalent to within a constant factor; 2 is generally used because the resulting algorithm descriptions are simpler.

Comment: to be more explicit, *n* is proportional to log(*N*)

Comment: That's not really more explicit than what I said; it's just swapping the dependent and independent variables in the relationship.

Comment: The *"Intuitively, ..."* part is very helpful and intuitive for understanding, many thanks.

Comment: I think it's better just to say that when you make a statement about complexity, you have to say what "n" is. Bit size is not always assumed (eg: sorting a list of length n).

Comment: @PaulHankin Bit size applies there, too, because you need to define some encoding of a list. Such an encoding has to worry about details like the size of each integer and a way of distinguishing one integer from another. Usually, you either assume a fixed-size integer, or you provide a variable-length encoding. Either way, the overhead works out to be a constant number of bits per integer, so the size of the bit string is linear in the number of items in the list.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, but what you're saying is not right. If you have a list of length n, with no duplicates (which is a typical pre-condition for most sorting algorithm analyses), the integers must have around log_2(n) bits each on average just so they're all different. So the bitsize can't be a linear multiple of the list length. Sometimes n is the bitsize (for example always in NP-complexity theory), and sometimes it's some parameter of the input. Or just look at 1.5 in Sedgwick's analysis of quicksort, and tell me that he's talking about bitsize: https://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/10analysis/

Comment: The bit size is what it is. If you say it's linear, that must be relative to something *else*, in this case the number of separate elements being represented. If you say there are `n` bits in the input, then the sorting algorithm you describe will end up having a sublinear number of operations, so that "O(n lg n) operations on a list of n items" and "O(lg n lg lg n) operations on a bit string of length n" are just two ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: OK. Your position is that the original question is unambiguous because n is always the bitsize. Mine is that it's ambiguous and one needs to say what n is. I've backed that up showing common examples where n is not the bitsize. I would also say that even if it was standard that n is always the bitsize it's _still_ better to say what you mean when you make a statement about complexity, because the source of the problem in this question is that two people have interpreted "n" differently.

Comment: I'm taking a formal view here (though with a lot of handwaving of details) in order to emphasize the difference between the input size and the magnitude of the arguments. I'm just saying you *can* provide a formal description of what it means for a list to be an argument; the details aren't relevant to this question and I'm not really interested in getting the details right in these comments.

Comment: @chepner: One of the details you handwave is that in the bit model, subtraction is not constant time. As it happens, that doesn't change the result (assuming my handwaving is correct), but in a formal view, the full argument would be needed. (It depends on the fact that the time to subtract is O(|denominator|) and shifting bits from numerator to denominator exponentially reduces the number of subtractions needed.)

Answer (score 1):

We usually measure the complexity as a function of *n*, the number of digits in *N*, which is proportional to log(*N*).

The worst case is *N*/1, in which case there are *N* steps. But *N*=exp(*n*), so the complexity is O(N)=O(exp(n)).